# Remove ViewController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app i have a login screen which i present modally on startup. After a successful login, the user gets redirected to a UITabBarController which has five UINavigationController (for the tabs).

On one tab, i have a button "logout", so that the user gets redirected back to the login screen.
That´s working fine.

But what i want to do is to load the UITabBarController every time the user logs in. That means, that the UITabBarController should NOT be reused. For now, the content in the tabs (i load data from web) stays the same, also when a new login has been done.

How can i release/pop/nil the UITabBarController with it´s UINavigationcontrollers?

---

What i have tried so far:

Thats the point where i push the user back to the login screen when he presses the "logout" button:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigContrLogin animated:YES];

[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; --> NOT WORKING
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; --> NOT WORKING
[self.tabBarController release]; ---> NOT WORKING
```

Can anybody help me please?

---

EDIT:
That´s how i add the UITabBarController. I do this when the user clicks the Login Button:

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];                    
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];       
[self.navigationController removeFromParentViewController];
```

---

EDIT2: I solved it. What i´m doing is when the user clicks the logout button, i call the navigation controller from the app delegate and use it to push the login viewcontroller.

```
MyAppDelegate *del = (MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [del.navControllerLogin pushViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove it from the superview and then release it? And then add new ViewControllers?

```
for (UIView *view in self.window.subviews){
        if (view == tabBarController.view) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];            
        }
}
[tabBarController release];
UITabBarController *newTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
newTabBarController.viewControllers = nil; //ADD NEW VIEWCONTROLLERS
[self.window addSubview:newTabBarController.view];
```

Comment: i do not have a window object here; do i need it to access the subviews?

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't do it with this way. Because managing (release/nil) a parent view from its subview is not a good practice.

1. init and show tabbar controller after app launch.
2. if user is not logged on, present loginviewcontroller. if already logged on no need.
3. after successfull login post a notification and capture it required places.
4. if user taps on logout, clear user credentials, user related data and present loginviewcontroller again.

Comment: that´s basically the way i´m doing it right now, but the main problem is that the tabbarcontroller is not loaded as a new instance after a logout...

Answer (score 0):

I'd add and remove both the modal view controller and tabbarcontroller from the appDelegate.

```
[myAppDelegate addLoginViewController];
[myAppDelegate removeLoginViewController];
[myAppDelegate addTabBarController];
[myAppDelegate removeTabBarController];
```

Comment: only the loginviewcontroller is initialized in the appdelegate, the tabbarcontroller with it´s subviews is initialized in the viewdidload of the loginviewcontroller.. you know what i mean?

Comment: I know what you mean, but I suggest it would be better to initialise and remove both from the appDelegate.